# wtforms returns only None

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have the following HTML, CSS and JS [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ps1ggsc0/2/). However, when I use the search from the top right side and press enter. Flask only get "None" and what was typed in search.

This is the route for the search:

```
@app.route("/quick_search/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
@app.route("/quick_search/<property_id>")
def quick_search(property_id=None):
    form = QuickSearch()
    print "???", form.propert_name.data
```

and this form class:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField, StringField, IntegerField, SelectMultipleField

class QuickSearch(Form):
    propert_name = StringField()
```

Why I only get `None` from `form.propert_name.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You name your field `propert_name` in the WTForms instance and in the Flask view. But in the HTML it is called `quick_search`.

You also use the attribute `type` twice in the `input`tag. You say `type="text"` and then you redefine `type` to `submit` later on. This shouldn't cause the problem, but worth it to take care…